# Parse Query Android - Match array of pointers to array of objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform

**I have two classes:**
SHOW: contains an array of pointers to the class SHOWTIMES
SHOWTIMES: contains a date attribute.

**I want to:**
Get the SHOWTIMES-object thats matches a selected date into an array. This is the "tempTimes" array that gets an array of ParseObjects from the function getTimes(). They turn out okey, i have checked the objectIds of them.

Then, i want to use those SHOWTIMES-objects in that array to find what SHOW-object contains any of temptimes-objects in its array of pointers, called "showtimes". If any array contains one of the objects from "tempTimes", then i have found a SHOW that has a SHOWTIME on the selected date, and it's added to the array "result". That works too, but my problem lies in the final lines of code in the Main section.

**How can i get my masterquery, wich is querying on SHOW objects, to fetch only the SHOWs that is in the array of SHOWs?** Because everything seems to turn out correct when i check the log, upuntil the final lines of code, because the masterQuery return 0 elements.

Any thoughts?
I happily explain more if you are intrested, since i have a hard time explaining the problem in an easy way!

Main

```
        temps = new ArrayList<>();
        tempresult = new ArrayList<>();
        tempTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        result = new ArrayList<>();

        tempTimes = getTimes();

        Date de = getDateFromDatePicket(dialog.getDatePicker());
        Date ds = getDateFromDatePicketStart(dialog.getDatePicker());

        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> showQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Show");

        showQuery.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("startDate", ds);
        showQuery.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("endDate", ds);
        showQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> likeList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.e("SKG: possiblesize ", String.valueOf(likeList.size()));
                    for (ParseObject likeItem : likeList) {
                        if(likeItem.getList("showtimes").contains(tempTimes)){
                            result.add(likeItem);
                        }


                        JSONArray jArray = likeItem.getJSONArray("showtimes").;
                        tempresult.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobject = null;
                            try {
                                jsonobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                String u = jsonobject.getString("objectId");
                                //Log.e("SKG: ustring", u);
                                tempresult.add(u);
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        for (String r : tempresult) {

                            if (tempTimes.contains(r)) {
                                result.add(likeItem);
                                Log.e("SKG R:", likeItem.getObjectId());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                Log.e("SKG resultsize: ", String.valueOf(result.size()));
            }

        });


        masterQuery.whereContainedIn("objectId", tempTimes);
```

getTimes-function:

```
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> getTimes() {
    final ArrayList<ParseObject> t1 = new ArrayList<>();

    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> showtimeQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Showtime");

    Date de = getDateFromDatePicket(dialog.getDatePicker());
    Date ds = getDateFromDatePicketStart(dialog.getDatePicker());

    showtimeQuery.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date", de);
    showtimeQuery.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", ds);
    showtimeQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> likeList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject likeItem : likeList) {
                    t1.add(likeItem);
                    Log.e("SKG: t1chosen ", likeItem.getObjectId());
                }
            }
            Log.e("SKG: t1size:", String.valueOf(t1.size()));
        }
    });
    return t1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's how `whereContainedIn` works.  Rather than a list of `ParseObject`, I think you will need to pass a list of object ids.